# Your parents were middle class (state 2). What is the probability that you are in the upper class (state 3)

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Problem: [image]

I am just starting to learn Markov chain. I know markov chain is like a conditional expectation. Can someone explains how the concept of Markov chain applies in here?

So will that be $P(3|2) \cdot P(1|3)$?

Comment: Can you answer this simpler question? Suppose that your parents were in state $2$; what is the probability that you are in state $3$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So it's $P(3|2)$. Then will that be like $P(3|2) \times P(1|2)$?

Comment: Not quite: for the second factor you want the probability that your child is in state $1$ given that you are in state $\color{red}3$, not state $2$.

Comment: Yes, now you’ve got it.